# Rails and Passenger Performance Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, carrierwave

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 on a vultr server with 1 CPU and 1GB RAM. And have launched a ruby on rails application on it via Passenger on Nginx. When I run `ps aux` on the server, I can see that several instances of  `Passenger RubyApp: /var/www/path_to_project/public` are running, and CPU usage is always 100%. I don't think it is a natural behavior. How can I solve it?

---

**Edit 1:** I realized that my problem (high CPU usage) starts when I want to upload a file in my rails app using CarrierWave. and after that , it remains 100%. Should I do anything with my nginx config to solve it?